# Cant get past "configurating man-db (amd64)

Tags: linux, configuration

[image]

It does not seem to get past this no matter if i do graphical or cli installation.
i have tried guided partition, guided partition withe lvm.
Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: How much did you wait? It may take a bit (it has to process a good number of man pages...)

Comment: Disk full? 20GB minimum is recommended.

Comment: increase to 3 cpu cores from 1 and that solved the issue for me